# Php Error. Notice: Undefined property: mysqliConn::$affected_rows

Tags: php

I have this code in OOP Php

```
include ('connection.php');


class NestedSet
{
/*Properties*/

/**
 * Mysqli object
 * @var object
 */
protected $db;

/**
 * Name of the database table
 * @var string
 */
public $table = 'tree';

/**
 * Primary key of the database table
 * @var string
 */
public $pk = 'id';

/**
 * Namefield in the database table
 * @var unknown_type
 */
public $name = 'name';

/*Methods*/

/**
 * Stores a Mysqli object for further use
 * @param object $mysqli Mysqli object
 * @return boolean true
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = mysqliConn::init();
    return true;
}

 protected static $instance = NULL;

// public static function get_instance()
// {
//     //if ( NULL === self::$instance )
//      //   self::$instance = new self;

//    // return self::$instance;
// }

/**
 * Creates the root node
 * @param string $name Name of the new node
 * @return boolean true
 */


public function createRootNode($name) {
    $this->db->query("LOCK TABLES " . $this->table . " WRITE");
    $sql = "SELECT rgt FROM " . $this->table . " ORDER BY rgt DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows == 0) {
        $lft = 1;
        $rgt = 2;
    } else {
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();
        $lft = $obj->rgt + 1;
        $rgt = $lft + 1;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table . " (" . $this->name . ", lft, rgt) VALUES ('" . $name . "', " . $lft . ", " . $rgt . ");";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    $this->db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
    return true;
}




}

?>
```

I create a new object for the class NestedSet in an other file called index.php

```
    <?php


    include("nested_set.php");




    $nested = new NestedSet(); //Create a NestedSet object
    $nested->createRootNode('root');

    ?>
```

I can write on db but the $rgt and $lft stays 2 and 1;
and this error is displayd :

```
"Notice: Undefined property: mysqliConn::$affected_rows in C:\wamp\www\hr-test\nested_set.php on line 67"
```

Any idea on what im doing wrong? 
Thank you!!

CODE FOR connection.php

```
   <?php

   define('SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('USERNAME', 'root');
   define('PASSWORD', '');
   define('DATABASE', 'hr_test2');

 class mysqliConn
 {
 private static $instance;
 private $connection;

 private function __construct()
 {
    $this->connection = new mysqli(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
 }

 public static function init()
 {
    if(is_null(self::$instance))
    {
        self::$instance = new mysqliConn();
    }

    return self::$instance;
 }


 public function __call($name, $args)
 {
    if(method_exists($this->connection, $name))
    {
         return call_user_func_array(array($this->connection, $name),    $args);
    } else {
         trigger_error('Unknown Method ' . $name . '()', E_USER_WARNING);
         return false;
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: What is the `mysqliConn` class?

Comment: mysqliConn is the connection class

Comment: Can you provide the code please?

Comment: @KlidiSpiro Are you using `codeigniter`??

Comment: Instead of `affected_rows` use `num_rows`

Comment: I think @Saty also makes an interesting point. Since you're using SELECT, you want the num rows instead of affected rows. Though whether that is implemented in the class...

Comment: @jon Stirling Just added the code  :)

Comment: @Saty using num_rows shows the same error

Comment: @KlidiSpiro Okay, so like you've got a `__call` method, you should add a `__get` method to access properties on the `$this->connection` object, but @RiggsFolly has given you a more specific answer.

Comment: Also I cannot see any benefit in wrapping an object oriented interface in another object. Especially as it adds absolutely no additional benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `mysqli->query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object which will contain information about the result of the query you need to use `$result` and not `$this->db->`

Also the `mysqli_result` object does not contain an `affected_rows` property you should use the `num_rows` property which does exist, but on the `$result` object instead.

You can also simplify the concatenation of the query string you create, although you should really use prepared statements.

```
public function createRootNode($name) {
    $this->db->query("LOCK TABLES " . $this->table . " WRITE");
    $sql = "SELECT rgt FROM " . $this->table . " ORDER BY rgt DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    // if ($this->db->affected_rows == 0) {
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        $lft = 1;
        $rgt = 2;
    } else {
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();
        $lft = $obj->rgt + 1;
        $rgt = $lft + 1;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} ( {$this->name}, lft, rgt) 
            VALUES ('$name', $lft , $rgt)";

    $this->db->query($sql);
    $this->db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: YES thank you very much now its working properly , $lft and $rgt get the right values and no error are displayed 
:) :)

Comment: @Saty Thanks. I do try my best.